# Doesn't a PC keyboard work in Mac using VMWare?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion

I use [this](https://assetlibrary.dstewart.com/ImageFolio43_files/gallery/Product_Images/Web/PNG/Zoom/37440.png) keyboard-mice combo on my PC and now I've installed El Capitan using VMWare, but the media keys aren't working on Mac virtual machine. Is there some specific config that I need to change in order to make them work? Or, it's not possible? I would like to use shortcuts to increase or decrease volume, at least. What could I do?

Comment: You'd need an Apple keyboard for the media keys to work... & probably a real Mac.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the keyboard mapping between a Windows keyboard and a Mac keyboard:

```
Windows logo key -> Command
Alt -> Option
Ctrl -> Control
```

The volume control keys vary depend on the brand or model of your computer.